# Tcp server works only locally

Tags: qt, tcpserver

Nowadays Im working tcp classes of qt. I know network (or socket) programming has a huge world of its own, and I'm very poor in terms of knowledge in this area.

Im aware of the fact that by creating a simple client and a server I cant say I know network programming,as you will understand from the following question.

Anyway, I create simple client and server programs. And they work fine locally. But when I try to change the client so that it tries to connect to the ip that I see on whatismyip.com and deliver it to a friend of mine, he can not connect to the server running on my machine. Again, if I rebuild the client so that it tries to connect to the ip that I see on cmd>ipconfig , he can not connect.

What do you suggest? I use a mobile modem device on my notebook working from usb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two main things you need to check / configure are:
A. Make sure you are listening on all IP addresses on your host computer

```
tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, SERVER_PORT);
```

B. **And this is important**: Your mobile modem is most likely doing NAT translation and the firewall on it is also most likely blocking the incoming requests. Go into your modem settings and set it to port forward any connection requests on whatever port you use to your computer's **internal** IP address. Also, make sure you have your Windows firewall set to allow connections on your chosen port.

Comment: I listen on all Ip addresses.For the B,I think I understood it.Im using 3g connection (and there is no such a setting),in this case i see that I wont be able to try my server in the public,and will try to be happy with the results on local :) Thank you.